# Why do the Survey Corps kill this character?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In chapter 76 of the manga of Attack on Titan, it appears that the Survey Corps. have killed

> Reiner Braun.

I don't understand why they killed him, especially when they needed information from him.

Comment: I'm not too sure myself, but I mean, they already have Annie Leonhardt and the bitch froze herself, so I think they figured Reiner and Bertolt would do the same if captured, therefore their main goal switched to killing them (a much easier task) and rather find answers in the basement at Eren's old house.

Comment: He is not shown to be dead yet, plus the corps had 2 targets, Bertolt Hoover and him, so it is fine for them to kill one of them. Plus, the titans shifter have extreme regeneration powers. Reiner getting nearly decapitated and still surviving. Bertolt's heart getting slashed and he still lives. Therefore, they thought that killing them would not 'kill' them, but only incapacitate them. Most importantly, the information they seek is in Eren's basement, so there is not need to keep Reiner or Bertolt alive anymore.

Comment: Actually they can't get any information from Reiner. Because Reiner actually had dissociative identity disorder. And seems like what he knows is less valuable than the information in Eren's basement

Comment: imo, there's no point getting rainer and bertholt alive because the answers they want is in the basement of eren's house. plus, the two will just keep saving each other and create more problems for them now that another intelligent titan is around.

Answer (score 3):

To begin with, it's not certain that Reiner is actually dead, the final frame of the manga shows the Armored Titan suffering intense damage, but as we haven't yet seen his corpse, it's best not to draw conclusions - he did just survive being half decapitated after all!

Secondly, even if he were to die, there is still the Colossal and Beast Titans that would be in possession of the same or similar information. As mentioned in Yokhen's comment, Annie too is in captivity and remains a potential source of information should she ever awaken. And as mentioned in Astral Sea's comment, it is believed that the information they need is in Eren's basement anyway.

Thirdly, and maybe most importantly, one of the Survey Corps. major objectives is the elimination of the duo that breached the wall in the first instance, as all other walls are in danger while they remain free. Therefore,  in Erwin's eyes at this time, the deaths of Reiner and Bertolt are likely far more advantageous than having them alive for questioning:

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

The latest chapter has Armin explicitly answer this:

> "There was no room for negotiation. After all, we are the ones with a lack of knowledge. We don't have the power to capture and restrain a human that can transform into a titan... ... And if we can't do that... this... was our only option. This ... was unavoidable."

But please note, there is no proof that he is dead despite the fact there should be.

Answer (score 0):

They never say the Reiner is dead . Reiner was saved by Zeke (Beast Titan)
[image: They updated the manga.]